# Upload android app on google play developer console

Tags: google-play-developer-api

I wan to upload android app on google play developer console

I got a problem about setting account to pay, 
and Google wallet only support UN or UK users now,

I am not from UN or UK.

How to set a google account to pay,and let the google play developer console can upload app.

Comment: do you have a credit card ?

Comment: already can apply payment in taiwan ,but I don't know which step to change it.

Comment: I don't know which step to make it succeful to use taiwan to apply ...

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I have followed while creating **`Google Play Developer Account`**

1. Sign Up for Google Play Developer Account https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/

[image: Google Play Developer console]

2. Accept Developer Agreement & Continue to Payment

[image: Make Payment]

3. Pay registration fee using credit or debit card
4. And finally complete your account details.

That's it you're done!
Even if I'm not from UN or UK I was able to pay using my debit card.

Thanks!